# String null values in Eclipse Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In my code, I try to check in my database whether the secretInfo entered has a null password or not, if yes it should do a certain function. However, the code probably has a mistake in it since it doesn't pass the required if statement.
In my database, I have a secret info with a null password. For this secret info, I am trying to add a password through my code. I tried the toast to see what retrieving the password gives me and it writes "DOES NOT EXIST" which means that the password is really null. But I can't figure out why it's not passing the if statement

This is the code of the function:

```
if (loginDataBaseAdapter.getPassthruSecInfo(secretInfo) == null){

     loginDataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(password);
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         }

if(loginDataBaseAdapter.getPassthruSecInfo(secretInfo) != null)

     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Already Exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                     }
```

This is the getPassthruSecretInfo method:

```
public String getPassthruSecInfo(String userName)
       {


          Cursor cursor=db.query("student", null, "SecretInfo"+"=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
           if(cursor.getCount()<1)
               return "DOES NOT EXIST";
           cursor.moveToFirst();
           String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("StdPass"));
           return password;
       }
```

Comment: How does the `getPassthruSecInfo()` method look like?

Comment: Does your `getPassthruSecInfo()` actually return `null`? Or does it return an empty string, e.g. ""?

Comment: @REACHUS I just included the method in the question

Comment: It looks like there's something wrong with your query.

Comment: @JasonC no I've written "null" in the database but I've already tried replacing null with "" in my code but that didn't work either

Comment: @REACHUS could you elaborate your answer?

Comment: Apparently your SQL statement returns 0 rows. Are you sure the syntax is right?

Comment: @REACHUS oh you're right, I haven't noticed that earlier. yes, the syntax should be right, I can't seem to find any mistake in it

Comment: So if it returns 0 rows, you should investigate your query. I'll add an answer to explain how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've removed the null values from my database and left the password empty. Instead of a ' null ' value or ' == "" ', the answer was .equals("")

```
if (loginDataBaseAdapter.getPassthruSecInfo(secretInfo).toString().equals("")){

     loginDataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(password);
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         }

if(!loginDataBaseAdapter.getPassthruSecInfo(secretInfo).toString().equals(""))

     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Already Exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your SQL statement returns 0 rows and therefore `cursor.getCount()` return always 0. In order to find out why, I suggest you to pull your SQLite database from the device using [this script](https://gist.github.com/jromero/8939416).

Then, create the right SQL query and after that input it to your application (currently you probably have wrong syntax and that's way there are no rows returned).

Comment: but i used the same query in another method and it returned 1 instead of 0... here is it

Comment: public String getSecretInfo(String SecretInfo){

        String where="SecretInfo=?";
           Cursor cursor=db.query("student", null, where, new String[]{SecretInfo}, null, null, null);
           if(cursor.getCount()<1)
               return "Does Not Exist";
           else return SecretInfo;


       }

Comment: Maybe you pass userName that is not present in the database?

Comment: yes ofcourse!! i can't believe i haven't noticed these mistakes... thank you a lot i'll fix it and try it now

Comment: It didn't work... Even though the getPassthruSecInfo method returns a null value(which means the problem isn't in that method anymore).